# refer to property defined in interface, kotlin

Tags: kotlin

guys, I am learning kotlin. From https://kotlinlang.org/docs/interfaces.html#properties-in-interfaces it says:

> Properties declared in interfaces can't have backing fields, and
> therefore accessors declared in interfaces can't reference them.

(I think the pronoun "them" at the end of quoted sentence should refer to "properties" rather than "fields". )

However the following code works. It seems that we can refer to properties. Why is `print(prop)` highlighted as red then?

```
interface MyInterface {
    val prop: Int // abstract

    val propertyWithImplementation: String
        get() = "foo"

    fun foo() {
        print(prop) // this is highlighted red but it works. what's does the author want to say?
    }
}

class Child : MyInterface {
    override val prop: Int = 29
}

fun main() {
    val c = Child()
    c.foo()
}
```

Besides, I noticed that in the above example `foo` is not accessor. So I tried following example and it works too:

```
interface User {
    val email: String
    val nickname: String
        get() = email.substringBefore('@') // aren't we referring to a property in accessor? why does this work then?
}
```

So what does the author want to say in here? what does "them" refer to?

Comment: based on this article I think it does refer to fields: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/backing-fields

Answer (score 2):

"Them" in this sentence means "fields".

Property is basically a getter (setter) and it could be optionally backed by a field. For technical reasons interfaces can't hold fields, so properties in interfaces have to be "fieldless". Property has to be either abstract or its implementation can only use e.g. other properties/functions, but it can't store/read any data directly. Note that referencing other properties does not break above rule, because, as I said, property is mainly a getter/setter, not a field.

`print(prop)` is highlighted as red, because... well, this is how automatic highlighter colored it... :-)